# Just transplated Zucchini and bean outside and noticing some white spots on leaves and brown stems

Tags: containers, transplanting, container-gardening, zucchini, beans

So a few days ago I transplanted my pole beans and Zucchini plants into containers. I'm noticing a few things on the plants.

1. We had a heavy rain and some wind a few days after I transplanted them and one of the pole beans leafs had fallen off. I'm now noticing browning on the stems.

[image: pole bean]

2. My zucchini leaves have big white spots on the leaves. I transplanted these 2-3 days ago. [image: zucchini leaves have big white spots]
3. My other Zucchini plant has little tiny white specs forming on its leaves [image: Zucchini]

Not sure if its just over watering. Pests? Not enough food? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

Did you ["harden off" your transplants](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-harden-off-seedlings.html) first?  I'm asking because this all looks like minor damage from not allowing your plants to gradually acclimate themselves to the outdoors, where the sun is stronger and the temperatures fluctuate and the wind blows, before being put outside all the time. The beige-brown patches on the Zucchini looks like sunburn.  The tiny white specs could also be sunburn, but it may be pests.  Keep an eye on the undersides of the leaves and treat with insecticidal soap if you find any creepy crawlies.  The browning of the stems on the beans may be sunburn as well, or a reaction to the higher level of light.

None of what I see here looks like death-dealing damage, however.  My guess they will outgrow it.  Keep your new transplants moist, but not soggy wet.  If the sunburn damage spreads, move them into more of a dappled sunlight spot for a few days until they get a bit tougher.

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to respond! I think what I did was not "harden them off" long enough. I'll let you know how they turn out